# Chrome uses old windows authentication credentials on Android

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have website thats uses windows authentication in .net core 5 / MVC and I'm need to use the site on mobile devices too(Android with chrome browser)

I have created a log off/change user page in the web site and it works fine on both Windows and Android in most cases.
The logic is the logoff page set a cooking and on next reload or page access the authentication filter returns a 401 and forces the user(or a new user) to login again

```
 if (userNameCookie.Value != string.Empty && userName == userNameCookie.Value)
 {
    filterContext.Result = new StatusCodeResult(401);
 }
```

The works fine but the problems happens when the logoff/login flows have been used 3 or 4 timers.
Then Chrome takes a set of old credentials from 2-3 users ago instead of the users that just logged in.

I cant reproduce the problem in debugging and it seems to only happens on android / chrome.

Is there any way to clear windows auth after a 401(dont think it should be necessary) or is there something else that can course the strange behaviour.

Regards
Birger

Comment: The easiest way is to clear chrome's cache, but how your application is configured, I don't know if this will have an impact.

Comment: Is there an easy way to clear Chromes chache from a MVC view ? via javascript or otherwise.